# "\n" is not being recognized properly in Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, command, newline, command-prompt

I'm trying to issue a command that requires a line break due to a formatting restriction.

I need to commit a file to a CVS repository, but the repository has a restriction that requires a message to be included in the following format.

```
Change #: <number>
Description: <description>
```

The command used to commit the file is:

```
cvs commit -m "Change #: <number>\nDescription: <description>" <filename>
```

However when I issue the command it doesn't seem to be properly recognizing the line break and it fails saying that I gave it an invalid Change # and no Description.

How can I make it recognize the new line without it trying to issue two separate commands?

Comment: Perhaps "\r\n" for a true Windows newline?

Comment: I gave that a try and it didn't work either :(

Comment: Try a carot ^ http://superuser.com/questions/150116/how-can-i-insert-a-new-line-in-a-cmd-exe-command

Comment: That's not working either.  The quotes seem to mess up the carot.

Comment: The legacy Windows command line isn't that sophisticated.  Unless `cvs` itself provides a mechanism for inserting line breaks, you'll need to use something else; Adam's suggestion of Powershell seems sound, if you don't want to use a GUI.

Comment: @tjwrona1992 - did the suggestion below work for you?

Comment: @AdamTuliper-MSFT I actually ended up finding another workaround.  I'm issuing the command from a Perl script.  I was originally calling it using a Perl `system` command but that wasn't working.  For some reason if you call it with backticks instead it functions correctly.  Its strange because I don't see any reason for this documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually attempting to call this command from a Perl script and found an acceptable workaround.  For some reason calling the command as a `system` command seems to fail, but if you call it using backticks it works fine.

```
# Fails
system 'cvs commit -m "Change #: <number>\nDescription: <description>" <filename>'

# Works
my $output = `cvs commit -m "Change #: <number>\nDescription: <description>" <filename>`
```

Whats funny is this difference in handling "\n" between using `system` commands and backticks doesn't seem to be documented anywhere.

Comment: [Documented here:](http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands) "If the argument [to system] is a scalar, system() uses the shell to execute the command".

Answer (score 1):

Try powershell in this format:

```
start-process -FilePath cvs.exe -ArgumentList "commit -m `"Change #:123 `nDescription:my description`""
```

Comment: How do you use a newline in a script?  Would it solve [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34491463/886887) too?

Comment: actually.. thats an interesting post. I didn't realize the parser was broken in that sense (if its indeed been verified). I believe start-process uses createprocess, if so this should be ok, but lets see.

Comment: Oh, you meant a Powershell script; my mistake.  Probably not relevant then.